# Partition dataframe into dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with chunks of information in it that have a row of `nan` in between them to separate. I want to take my initial large dataframe and convert it into a dictionary of dataframes in which the elements of the dictionary are the individual chunks.

Ex df:

```
0    1    2    3    4

x    s    a    g    g
q    r    w    l    p 
z    l    w    q    k
nan  nan  nan  nan  nan
k    u    l    p    a
m    1    l    9    0 
o    p    q    1    7
```

The idea is to take this dataframe and create a dictionary of dataframes with two (or more if there are more "chunks") dataframes

df1

```
0    1    2    3    4

x    s    a    g    g
q    r    w    l    p 
z    l    w    q    k
```

df2

```
0    1    2    3    4

k    u    l    p    a
m    1    l    9    0 
o    p    q    1    7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
import more_itertools as mit
m = df.dropna(how='all')
l = [df.loc[i] for i in mit.consecutive_groups(m.index)]
print(l[0],'\n',l[1])
```

---

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  x  s  a  g  g
1  q  r  w  l  p
2  z  l  w  q  k 
   0  1  2  3  4
4  k  u  l  p  a
5  m  1  l  9  0
6  o  p  q  1  7
```

Similarly for a dictionary you can use:

```
import more_itertools as mit
m = df.dropna(how='all')
d = {f"df{e}":df.loc[i] for e,i in enumerate(mit.consecutive_groups(m.index))}
print(d['df0'],'\n\n',d['df1'])
```

---

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  x  s  a  g  g
1  q  r  w  l  p
2  z  l  w  q  k 

   0  1  2  3  4
4  k  u  l  p  a
5  m  1  l  9  0
6  o  p  q  1  7
```